# How come there can be a margin when margin is set to 0px

Tags: css, margin

See the code below:

HTML

```
<input class="input-form" type="text">
<input class="input-form" type="password">
       ​
```

CSS

```
.input-form{
    width:250px;
    height:30px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    margin:0px;
}
```

JSFIddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/TypYn/

My problem : I do not get why there is a margin between the two inputs eventhough I did set the margin to 0px. Thank you in advance for your replies. Cheers. Marc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is, HTML interprets the line break as a space. Just change your HTML to this:

```
<input class="input-form" type="text"><input class="input-form" type="password">
```

Comment: Indeed that solves the problem. Thank you :) But what a nightmare! That can make the code quickly unreadable if I can't break the line...

Comment: Unfortunately, it will. Kind of a Catch-22

Comment: Yes. Line breaks convert to spaces, but only up to one space in a row, without something else between it. To get more than one space in a row, you'd need to use `&nbsp;`